# problem compiling ethzasl_icp_mapping on indigo

Tags: ros, ethzasl-icp-mapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to compile the package `ethzasl_icp_mapping` on indigo and I get this error:

```
*** No rule to make target `/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-libpointmatcher-1.2.2-0trusty-20140805-1228/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpointmatcher.so', needed by `/datos/ros_ws/ethz-asl/devel/lib/libpointmatcher_ros.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [ethzasl_icp_mapping-indigo_devel/libpointmatcher_ros/CMakeFiles/pointmatcher_ros.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. I've also installed the packages `ros-indigo-libpointmatcher` and `ros-indigo-libnabo`.

Please, help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194687/problem-compiling-ethzasl_icp_mapping-on-indigo/) by [Ferherranz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4075/ferherranz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me, uninstalling the system packages ros-indigo-libpointmatcher and ros-indigo-libnabo helped.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have it working using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. You need the indigo branches of the following three packages: ethzasl_icp_mapper, libpointmatcher, libnabo. Use the following commands to get them:

```
git clone -b indigo_devel https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping.git
git clone -b release/indigo/libnabo https://github.com/ethz-asl/libnabo-release.git
git clone -b release/indigo/libpointmatcher https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher-release.git
```

Once you have those you can run a catkin_make_isolated. Source your setup.bash from the devel_isolated folder and you should be good to go.

---

Originally posted by [neptun](https://answers.ros.org/users/7431/neptun/) with karma: 23 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2